# Device Simulators in XPM

Tags: experience-manager

We have following Device simulators in XPM.

1. Apple Iphone 5
2. Blackberry Bold 9650
3. HTC One X+
4. Apple iPad 4gen
5. Apple iPad Mini
6. Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1
7. HTC Wildfire
8. Nokia Lumia 920
9. Motorolz KRZR K1

Can we create/customize new simulator in XPM?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. As per the [product documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-8AC922A2-17AE-4907-8319-A7CF2B9543D4) (login required), you can configure the types of devices available for users to edit and preview content in Experience Manager in the Devices.xml configuration file.

You need to supply the following for your new device:

- Name
- Icon
- userAgent string
- Orientation
- 'Background' Image
- Viewport size and position